# Why am I getting this MySQL error - 'You have an error in your SQL syntax...'?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm getting the following MySQL error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'SET type =
>   'movie', SET category = 'New', SET
>   music = 'Pop', SET' at line 1

Heres my query:

```
UPDATE music_content
SET    title = 'Classic',
SET    type = 'movie',
SET    category = 'New',
SET    music = 'Pop',
SET    audience = 'Everyone'
WHERE  id = '6'
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong? - all the columns and tables exist and all the data is escaped (using mysql_real_escape_string()). Furthermore I have a valid/connected MySQL connection.

MySQL Version: 5.1.41.

Comment: If i'm not wrong: SETs doesn't have to be separated by a , at all.

Answer (score 7):

The [UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) uses only one `SET` even when multiple columns are being updated.

So try:

```
UPDATE music_content 
SET title = 'Classic',
type = 'movie',
category = 'New',
music = 'Pop',
audience = 'Everyone' 
WHERE id = '6'
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to have "SET" once:

```
UPDATE music_content SET title = 'Classic', type = 'movie', category = 'New', music = 'Pop', audience = 'Everyone' WHERE id = '6'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only have one `SET`, like so:

```
PDATE music_content SET title = 'Classic', type = 'movie', category = 'New', music = 'Pop',  audience = 'Everyone' WHERE id = '6'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need one SET.  Remove the others and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have an abundance of SET's in your statement. Drop all but the fist one. For more information, please see the [UPDATE Syntax documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).